# Cannot instantiate TwoCaptcha object in .Net 6

Tags: c#, 2captcha

I am trying to integrate 2Captcha service in my .Net6 Application.

I have installed this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/2captcha-csharp/

Following their official documentation: https://github.com/2captcha/2captcha-csharp

I added the namespace: `using TwoCaptcha.Captcha;`

But I am not able to instantiate the object:

```
TwoCaptcha solver = new TwoCaptcha('YOUR_API_KEY');
reCAPTCHA captcha = new reCAPTCHA();
```

Getting error here.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Any time you're "getting error" [you need to tell us what the error is](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).